# Checking to see if an element has a dynamically added class in an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I gave an element two dynamically added classes (one for uniform styling, the other for differentiation in programming their click functions). Here is the block of code:

```
$(document).on('click', "section.notelink", function() {
    chrome.storage.local.get('noteTitleList', function (x) {
        var titleSet = x.noteTitleList;
        for(var c = 0; c < titleSet.length; c++) {
            var noteTitle = titleSet[c].substr(5);
            if($(this).hasClass('note-'+c)) {
                alert('check');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The element should have a class of notelink (which it does find) and note-# (number ranges from 0 - 5 currently). I tried checking to see if it had a class using the jquery hasClass method without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem with scoping, since you are calling `$(this)` after the value that `this` is pointing no longer refers to the current jQuery DOM node (it refers to the chrome method). Capture your dom node before entering the chrome method:

```
$(document).on('click', "section.notelink", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    chrome.storage.local.get('noteTitleList', function (x) {
        var titleSet = x.noteTitleList;
        for(var c = 0; c < titleSet.length; c++) {
            var noteTitle = titleSet[c].substr(5);
            if($this.hasClass('note-'+c)) {
                alert('check');
            }
        }
    });
});
```